# Get a count of active/stale connections on Database Resource in Tomcat

Tags: java, database, oracle, tomcat

I have web app running on tomcat and I have configured a database datasource which is an oracle database. But lately there have been lot of activities going on my app and its throwing connection pool exceptions.
I want to create a JSP which displays the current state of the db resource like active/stale/abandoned connections to the db server.
Is this a good option or there are other ways which can show us the connections on database without having to actually access DB server(I don't have access to admin panel of the database)

Comment: What exceptions are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I know [Druid](https://github.com/alibaba/druid) can meet your needs